# Hide Sender IP address in Mail

Tags: email, smtp

I'm currently trying to improve my emails discretion to prevent, as far as conveniently possible, a reader to tell (just by reading the headers) from where (which country, which type of device etc) I wrote the email.

I'm sending mails through a provider's SMTP server using a domain name I own. I customized the message-id and host name and domain. Is there a way to hide the sender's IP address (and provider domain) or to make it appear similar everytime ?

(Apart from using a VPN, which I think should work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many SMTP providers (e.g. yahoo mail, gmail, etc.) include the sender's IP address in the message headers, for tracking purposes.  But, there is no reason that the sender's IP address `must` be included in the headers.  There are some SMTP providers (e.g. http://www.ultrasmtp.com) which do not includes the sender's IP address in the headers.